# How can I parse a json string on a txt file?

Tags: r, json

I need to parse two columns from a txt file in which I have:
first column: id (with only one value)
second column: parameters (which has more json fields inside, SEE BELOW).

Here an example:

```
ID;PARAMETERS
Y;"""Pr""=>""22"", ""Err""=>""0"", ""DryT""=>""0"", ""Lang""=>""99"", ""Opt1""=>""67"", ""Opt2""=>""0"", 
S;"""Pr""=>""5"", ""Err""=>""255"", ""Opt1""=>""0"", ""Opt2""=>""0"", ""Opt3""=>""55"", ""Opt4""=>""0"", 
K;"""Pr""=>""1"", ""Err""=>""0"", ""DryT""=>""0"", ""Lang""=>""21"", ""Opt1""=>""0"", ""Opt2""=>""0"", 
P;"""Pr""=>""90"", ""Err""=>""0"", ""DryT""=>""0"", ""Lang""=>""20"", ""Opt1""=>""0"", ""Opt2""=>""0"",
```

My dataset is in csv format, but I have tried also to transform it in a txt file or in json file and I tried to import it in R but I cannot parse the two columns.
I would like to obtain each parameter in one column, and If an ID does not have a parameter I need NA

Can you help me please?

I have tried this R code but it does not work:

```
setwd("D:/")
df <- read.delim("file name", header = TRUE, na.strings = -1)
install.packages("jsonlite")
library(jsonlite)
filepath<-"file name"
prova <- fromJSON(filepath)

prova <- fromJSON(filepath)
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can import the csv directly in Rstudio with multiples functions :

`data <- read.csv("your_data.csv")`

Otherwise you can load it by looking in 'Import dataset' in the Environment tab. It will open a new window in which you can browse to your file without setting working directory.

To set NA for 0 values, here is an example

```
# I create a new data for example, 
# you will have another one if you succed in importing your data.
data <- data.frame(ID = c("H1","H2","H3"), PARAMETERS_Y = c(42,0,3))
data[which(data$PARAMETERS_Y == 0),2] = NA
```

It look for rows in the Param column which are equal to 0 and replace them with NAs. Don't forget to change the column name to match your data loaded previously